# Existence of special transversal on foliation

Tags: differential-geometry, fundamental-groups, foliations, holonomy, cartan-geometry

This is a somewhat technical question about a line in Sharpe's book **Differential Geometry: Cartan's Generalization of Klein's Erlangen Program** in the proof of the structure theorem, Theorem 8.3. We have assumed that the leaf space of a foliation $M/\sim$ is Hausdorff. Because of this, each leaf $\mathcal{L}$ is closed and is in particular an embedded submanifold. Using the hypotheses that a foliation has trivial holonomy (w.r.t. transversals) and each leaf has finitely generated fundamental group, he concludes that a given leaf has a transversal that meets each leaf at most once. How can I justify this?

Because each leaf is embedded, we can certainly choose a transveral intersecting a given leaf exactly once. But the tricky part is doing this uniformly for all the leaves meeting the transversal. If we replaced the assumption that leaves $\mathcal{L}$ have finitely generated fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathcal{L})$ with the stronger assumption that each leaf is compact, then Theorem 7.8 of Sharpe guarantees the existence of a tubular neighborhood $U$ of $\mathcal{L}$ with a leaf-preserving diffeomorphism $U\cong \mathcal{L}\times T$ for some transversal $T$, which would give a transversal meeting each leaf at most once.

The main application of finitely generated fundamental group and trivial holonomy I've seen is that, given a transveral of a leaf, we can pick a single open subset of the transversal where the entire fundamental group acts as the identity.

Thanks!